# exclude nested children

Tags: jquery

The following script enables/disables their nested form controls using a `for:x` class name. The problem is that nested `for:y` elements are being enabled when they shouldn't be. They should only be enabled when the nested `for:y` is enabled.

Can someone provide me with an additional filter to exclude the form elements that are inside a nested `for:*` class?

In other words, given the example below, when `losssold` is checked then all the child inputs of `for:losssold` should be enabled except for the child element elements inside `for:has-buy-sell-agreementtrue` if `has-buy-sell-agreementtrue` is not also checked.

So I thought it would be easier to just figure to exclude those elements in `for:has-buy-sell-agreementtrue`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('[class*="for:"]').each(function(){
   var klass=$(this).attr('class'),element;
   var that = this;
   $.each(klass.split(' '),function(index,value){
       if(!value)return;
       if (value.substr(0,4)=='for:')
           element=value.substr(4);
   });
   $('[name="' + $('#'+element).attr('name') + '"]')
       .click(function(){
           $(that).toggleClass('disabled', !$('#'+element).is(':checked'))
               .find('input,select,textarea') /* insert edge case here */
               .each(function(){
                   if ($('#'+element).is(':checked'))
                      $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
                   else
                       $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
               });
       })
       .trigger('click');
});
</script>

  <li>What would you like to see happen to your business when you (or a co-owner) die, become disabled, or retire? <br/>
    <ul><li><label><input type="radio" name="loss" id="losssold" value="sold"/> Sold to other Owners/another Business</label>
        <ul class="for:losssold">
          <li>Do you have a buy-sell agreement?<br/>
            <label><input type="radio" name="has-buy-sell-agreement" id="has-buy-sell-agreementtrue" value="true"/> Yes</label> 
            <label><input type="radio" name="has-buy-sell-agreement" id="has-buy-sell-agreementfalse" value="false"/> No</label><br/>
            <ol class="for:has-buy-sell-agreementtrue"> <!-- nested for class; inner elements shouldn't be affected -->
              <li><label for="buy-sell-last-updated">When was the agreement last updated?</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="buy-sell-last-updated" id="buy-sell-last-updated" value=""/>
              </li>
              <li>Is the agreement funded?<br/>
                <label><input type="radio" name="buy-sell-is-funded" id="buy-sell-is-fundedtrue" value="true"/> Yes</label> 
                <label><input type="radio" name="buy-sell-is-funded" id="buy-sell-is-fundedfalse" value="false"/> No</label>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: Could you state the question clearer? `The problem is that nested elts are being enabled. They should only be enabled when nested are enabled.` Do you mean a for:xxx elt must be enabled only if it's children fox:xxx elts are enabled?

Comment: @culebrón I've tried to clarify by editing my post, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by recursively parsing the child `for^=` elements when the event was fired.

```
$(function(){
    $('[class^="for:"]').each(function(){
        var that=this;
        function getElement(forElement){
             var klass=$(forElement).attr('class'),element;
             $.each(klass.split(' '),function(index,value){
                 if(!value)return;
                 if(value.substr(0,4)=='for:'){
                     element=value.substr(4);
                     return false;
                 }
             });
             return '#' + element;
         }
         function parse(forElement){
             var element = getElement(forElement);
             if (element == '#') return;
             $(forElement)
                 .toggleClass('disabled', !$(element).is(':checked'))
                 .find('input,select,textarea')
                     .each(function(){
                         if ($(element).is(':checked'))
                             $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
                         else
                             $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
                     })
                 .end()
                 .find('[class^="for:"]')
                     .each(function() { parse(this); });
         }
         var element = getElement(this);
         $('[name="' + $(element).attr('name') + '"]')
             .click(function() { parse(that); });
         parse(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ouch. Sucks that even with jQuery there's not an easier way to solve this. Glad ya figured it out though!

Comment: yeah, i'm open to any ideas for refactoring :)

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for a 'not()' filter. At the line you specified, try this:

```
.find('input,select,textarea').not("[class='for\\:has-buy-sell-agreementtrue'] *")
```

Or with the variables you mentioned:

```
.find('input,select,textarea').not("[class='for\\:" + element + "true'] *")
```

I don't think the usual class selector (the dot) would work because jQuery might think it's a pseudo selector like 'checked' or 'contains.'

**EDITED**

Okie dokie, I'll give it one more shot:

IF you wanted to narrow the number of input, select, and textrea elements returned, then you could either narrow the 'find' function or broaden the 'not' function. For example, If you wanted to take action only on form elements inside form_1, then you'd do this:

```
.find('#form_1 input, #form_1 select, #form_1 textarea').not("[class='for\\:" + element + "true'] *");
```

Here's a little more detail on the 'not' filter.
The 'not' filter does the following:

1. Finds all elements in the **entire** document that its selector (the 'not' selector) specifies.
2. Compares the elements that it finds in step 1 with the list of elements in the calling 'find' function.
3. Removes all elements that are the same between the two sets.
4. **The resulting set of elements includes only those elements that were in the original find, but were not in the 'not' function.**

Therefore, the set of elements above would only include input, select, and textarea elements that were not inside the class=for:has-buy-sell-agreement.

Oh, and I copied and pasted this filter onto a simple html document and it worked. So you should be all set!

Later Dave,
Best of luck.

Comment: this wouldn't work because the input/select/textarea are not decorated with the "for:" attribute. There is also, some hard coding here, it is not necessarily true that the element is going to end with "true"

Comment: There's an asterisk after the class selector that ya didn't see :-) This would select all items below the item with the given class, which is what you're looking for (I think). And the 'true' hard coding was a simple example of how to generalize the class selector based on previous code. :-) Hope this helps!

Comment: ooooh, i'll check this out, sorry about that

Comment: wouldn't that exclude everthing? I think do something a little more indepth than this and exclude what in the nested `for:` elements

Comment: Allll righty, I gave it another go just for good measure. hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

The `filter` function is nice for removing items that do *not* match an expression, so you could change this:

```
.find('input,select,textarea')
```

into this?

```
.find('input,select,textarea')
    .filter(function() {
        // return false to remove an element from the set
        return $(this)
                .closest('[class^="for\\:"]')
                .hasClass('for:' + element);
    })
```

The idea is to remove any inputs, selects, or textareas, which have a closest parent other than your desired parent.

Notice also that I double-escaped your `:` character in your selector. The `:` is an unusual character to use in a class name because it implies "pseudo" selectors and will also trip up jquery (unless you escape it, as I have above).

Good luck!

---

**EDIT**

Ahh, yes, we would want the *disabling* to propogate down through the nested "for:" divs, but not the *enabling*.... We could modify this as follows by moving around the filtering. (Filter was moved to a separate function to make it more readable.)

```
.find('input,select,textarea')
.each(function() {
    if ($('#'+element).is(':checked')) {
        if (isDirectDescendant(this, element)) {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
 });

function isDirectDescendant(e, element) {
     return $(e)
            .closest('[class^="for\\:"]')
            .hasClass('for:' + element);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'd probably recommend for simplicity and consistency to just replace all of your `for:` instances into `for-` ?  Also notice I changed `class*=` into `class^=` so that the class name must start with this sequence instead of merely containing it.

Comment: this is close, however the nested elements aren't disabling now.

Comment: I should also note, this relies on jQuery's ordering to be consistent, whereby inputs are selected from "parent" divs before they are from "children" divs... (Otherwise you might find yourself disabling something already enabled) I am hoping this shouldn't be a problem. Good luck!

Comment: Hmmm, that did some strange things, and I think I actually found a bug in jquery. Escaping `\\:` works in the `$` function but not in the `find` method.

Answer (score 0):

Restructuring the HTML is the key:

```
<li>What would you like to see happen to your business when you (or a co-owner) die, become disabled, or retire? <br/>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="loss" id="losssold" value="sold"/>
            <label for="losssold">  Sold to other Owners/another Business
            </label>
            <ul class="nestedList">
                <li>Do you have a buy-sell agreement?<br/>
                    <input type="radio" name="has-buy-sell-agreement" id="has-buy-sell-agreementtrue" value="true"/>
                    <label for="has-buy-sell-agreementtrue">    Yes
                    </label> 
                    <input type="radio" name="has-buy-sell-agreement" id="has-buy-sell-agreementfalse" value="false"/>
                    <label for="has-buy-sell-agreementfalse">   No
                    </label>
                    <br/>
                    <ol class="nestedList">
                        <li>
                            <label for="buy-sell-last-updated">
                                When was the agreement last updated?
                            </label>
                            <br/>
                            <input type="text" name="buy-sell-last-updated" id="buy-sell-last-updated" value=""/>
                        </li>
                        <li>Is the agreement funded?
                            <br/>
                            <input type="radio" name="buy-sell-is-funded" id="buy-sell-is-fundedtrue" value="true"/> 
                            <label for="buy-sell-is-fundedtrue">    Yes
                            </label> 
                            <input type="radio" name="buy-sell-is-funded" id="buy-sell-is-fundedfalse" value="false"/> 
                            <label for="buy-sell-is-fundedfalse">   No
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I moved your `<input>` tags outside of the labels so that all inputs had a direct parent of `<li>`.  This made the jQuery easier to come up with.  Here's what I have:

```
$('.nestedList input, .nestedList select, .nestedList textarea').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('input:radio').click(function() {
    $('[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() != 'false')
        {
            if(this.checked == true)
            {
                $(this).siblings(".nestedList").children('li').children('input, select, textarea').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else
            {
                $(this).siblings(".nestedList").children('li').children('input, select, textarea').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I've tested this with variations of your HTML and seems to work fine.